# Trying to port my socketio client from js to python but it is not working

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, socket.io, client

I have the following JS code that works great to connect to a socket via the socketio client library:

```
userApi = 'userapiaccesfskdglk';
userAccess = 'useaccesfjkasdfdlkf2';

var axios = require('axios');
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('wss://test-meownow12345.com:4566');

socket.emit('Authenticate', {api: userApi, access: userAccess});

socket.on('Party', function(party) {
    console.log('party', party)

})
```

These are not the actual userApi, userAccess, or urls used, but using them still gets the same point across.

This is what i have in python, that to me looks like an exact port but is not working:

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


def on_party():
    print('connect')

userApi = 'userapiaccesfskdglk'
userAccess = 'useaccesfjkasdfdlkf2'

with SocketIO('wss://test-meownow12345.com', 4566, LoggingNamespace) as socketIO:
    socketIO.emit('Authenticate', {'api': userApi, 'access': userAccess})
    socketIO.on('Party', on_party)
```

It seems like it is equivalent but it is clearly not as the code cannot get past the following line that opens the socket.io connection:

```
with SocketIO('wss://test-meownow12345.com', 4566, LoggingNamespace) as socketIO:
```

In my console it prints out the following log errors that just repeat:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): wss
WARNING:socketIO-client:wss:4566//test-meownow12345.com/socket.io [engine.io waiting for connection] HTTPConnectionPool(host='wss', port=4566): Max retries exceeded with url: //test-meownow12345.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1523668232386-0 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x105000278>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
```

I'm not really sure what this means.

I have tried changing the line giving this message and drop the 'wss://' part to make it:

```
with SocketIO('test-meownow12345.com', 4566, LoggingNamespace) as socketIO:
```

but this still fails, albeit with a new message in the logs that repeats:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): test-meownow12345.com
WARNING:socketIO-client:test-meownow12345.com:4566/socket.io [engine.io waiting for connection] ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (2): test-meownow12345.com
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (3): test-meownow12345.com
```

Any help is really appreciated, this is quite a frustrating problem.

Comment: Did you opened port 4566?
Please try to `$ telnet test-meownow12345.com 4566`

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn i will try this but doesnt the fact that it worked with JS imply the port is open?

Comment: I'm just guess that because your source code seem okay.

Comment: @MarkKeane, please try with `with SocketIO('https://test-meownow12345.com', 4566, LoggingNamespace) as socketIO:`. Looking at the library code, it seems that is what they expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `SocketIO` class

```
class SocketIO(EngineIO):
```

It inherits from `EngineIO` which has `__init__` as

```
class EngineIO(LoggingMixin):

    def __init__(
            self, host, port=None, Namespace=EngineIONamespace,
            wait_for_connection=True, transports=TRANSPORTS,
            resource='engine.io', hurry_interval_in_seconds=1, **kw):
        self._is_secure, self._url = parse_host(host, port, resource)
        self._wait_for_connection = wait_for_connection
```

And definition of `parse_host` is

```
def parse_host(host, port, resource):
    if not host.startswith('http'):
        host = 'http://' + host
    url_pack = parse_url(host)
    is_secure = url_pack.scheme == 'https'
    port = port or url_pack.port or (443 if is_secure else 80)
    url = '%s:%s%s/%s' % (url_pack.hostname, port, url_pack.path, resource)
    return is_secure, url
```

This indicates that the usage should be like below

```
with SocketIO('https://test-meownow12345.com', 4566, LoggingNamespace) as socketIO:
    socketIO.emit('Authenticate', {'api': userApi, 'access': userAccess})
    socketIO.on('Party', on_party)
```